# Use Import command in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this node package installed https://github.com/jakearchibald/indexeddb-promised/blob/master/lib/idb.js, and am trying to use it.

I am trying to use this command:

```
(Import idb from 'idb')
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

What should I do to solve this error?

Comment: Node supports some parts of es6 but I don't believe `import` is one of them. I believe you still need babel or another transpiler for that.

Comment: ^ is the correct answer. What you should do is write your code in CommonJS style: `let idb = require('idb')`.

Comment: @Chev How can I use Babel with node.js to make this ?

Comment: @Mick C When I use your command. I get this Error : Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: They have some pretty decent instructions on [their site](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/).

Comment: Wait, `require` is undefined? Wat? You really running node.js or are you running your javascript in the browser? Is `window` defined?

Comment: @AbdulAzizSabra That's not possible. `require` is always defined in Node.js. How are you starting your app? It should be something like `node app.js` on your command line. Node.js is totally separate from the browser.

Comment: require work with server code, but not working with browser. So I need Import.

Comment: @AbdulAzizSabra `import` [doesn't work *anywhere* yet.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Browser_compatibility) Check out [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) if you want to have modularized code that runs in the browser.

Comment: There is no require or import in the browser. You need to either A) Put a `<script>` tag for each script you need on the page, or B) Use a bundler like Mike mentioned. Browserify and Webpack are where you'll want to begin, but you'll have some learning to do. They bundle all your scripts up into a single script you can embed on the page, but it allows you to use require and import during development.

Comment: In this Course https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud899/lessons/6381510082/concepts/63774101910923 .The teacher use Import with Browser Code (to use indexeddb code with Promises).  But he didnot speak how he did that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js - SyntaxError: Unexpected token import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import)

Answer (score 2):

You can use babel to transpile your code in ES6 syntax to ES5 in a transparent way for your develop. This is a part of my package.json in a demo app

```
 {
  "name": "**********",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js --exec babel-node --presets es2015,stage-2"
  },
  "author": "Borja Tur",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.4.19",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.5.0"
  }
}
```

1. Install the same "**devDependencies**"
2. Install nodemon globally "**npm install nodemon -g**"
3. Configure your npm **start** command with the same of my package.json changing "**server.js**" with your entry file in the app
4. Run "**npm start**"

Then you can use import syntax

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is still not working with the same error.

Comment: "import" is used in lowercase maybe this cause the problem?

Comment: This is a sample use on my server.js => import express from 'express';

Comment: First I make This Command: npm install idp. and in my file I use this command : import idb from 'idp'; and I get this error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Comment: After install this "devDependencies" shoulde I make require for this packages? @Borjs Tur

Comment: It's not necessary, this afternoon I will upload the project to github and post here the link for your tests

Comment: @AbdulAzizSabra look at the link of my repository, it's a working example with es6 syntax  https://github.com/borjatur/Node-api-es6-JWT if it's any help please vote up the answer

Comment: @AbdulAzizSabra Please vote up and make the answer correct friend ;)