# Node.js - SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6

I don't understand what is wrong.
Node v5.6.0
NPM v3.10.6

The code:

```
function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
    import express from 'express'
};
```

The error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:140:18)
    at node.js:1001:3
```

Comment: Use transpiler like Babel to use import in Nodejs as it is not natively supported in nodejs.There is best alternative of import is require so go with that.

Comment: Checkout support for import () the nodejs v16  - https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html

Comment: @BHUVNESHKUMAR: Is your statement still correct in 2022?

Answer (score 595, accepted):

**Node 13+** Since [Node 13](https://github.com/nodejs/node/releases/tag/v13.2.0), you can use either the `.mjs` extension, or set `{"type": "module"}` in your package.json. You **don't** need to use the `--experimental-modules` flag. [Modules is now marked as stable in node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_modules_ecmascript_modules)

**Node 12** Since [Node 12](https://thecodebarbarian.com/nodejs-12-imports), you can use either the `.mjs` extension, or set `"type": "module"` in your package.json. And you need to run node with the `--experimental-modules` flag.

**Node 9** In [Node 9](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v9.6.0/), it is enabled behind a flag, and uses the `.mjs` extension.

```
node --experimental-modules my-app.mjs
```

---

While `import` is indeed part of ES6, <strike>it is unfortunately not yet supported in NodeJS by default, and has only very recently landed support in browsers.</strike>

See [browser compat table on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Browser_compatibility) and [this Node issue](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/53).

From James M Snell's [Update on ES6 Modules in Node.js](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c) (February 2017):

> Work is in progress but it is going to take some time — We’re currently looking at around a year at least.

Until support shows up natively ([now marked stable in Node 13+](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_modules_ecmascript_modules)), <strike>you'll have to continue using classic `require` statements</strike>:

```
const express = require("express");
```

If you really want to use new ES6/7 features in NodeJS, you can compile it using Babel. [Here's an example server](https://github.com/babel/example-node-server).

Comment: does anyone know if node 10 will ship with support enabled by default? (due for debut next month)

Comment: node --experimental-modules my-app.mjs  what is meaning of "--experimental-modules" and "my-app.mis"

Comment: @Leo `--experimental-modules` is the flag to enable it, and `my-app.mjs` is the file.

Comment: @Scimonster...Thanks ....it is throwing a wraning...node: bad option: --experimental-modules

Comment: @Leo Make sure you're using Node 9 at least.

Comment: @Scimonster......node --experimental-modules my-app.mjs
(node:12176) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
{ Error: Cannot find module /C:/Users/WittyParrot/Documents/card-test-project/src/my-app.mjs
    at search (internal/modules/esm/DefaultResolve.js:23:12)test-project/src/my-app.mjs
    at search (internal/modules/esm/DefaultResolve.js:23:12)....throwing a warning could not find my-app.js....please suggest....i installed node version 9.11.1

Comment: @Leo You need to replace my-app.mjs with the name of your file.

Comment: @Scimonster...i tired with replacing file name ...node --experimental-modules app.mjs
(node:1740) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
{ Error: Cannot find module /C:/Users/WittyParrot/Documents/card-test-project/src/app.mjs
    at search (internal/modules/esm/DefaultResolve.js:23:12)
    at Loader.resolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/DefaultResolve.js:60:11)....my file name app.ts ..so changed to app.mjs...but it throwing wraning that it did n't get the file

Comment: Still requires a flag in v12 https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_ecmascript_modules

Comment: Seems Node v13.2.0 can't import or import() ES modules as '.js' except when there's a package.json with type: module somewhere above it. esm still has utility in those cases.

Comment: Off topic, but I can't install node 14, because it no longer supports windows 7. It's sad, that if I want full support for import/export without any flags, then I have to upgrade my operating system.

Comment: Well **no one**, [not even Microsoft support Windows 7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-365/windows/end-of-windows-7-support) so that seems reasonable. You could also make the same argument for Windows 95.... @LajosMeszaros

Answer (score 68):

Unfortunately, Node.js doesn't support ES6's `import` yet.

To accomplish what you're trying to do (import the Express module), this code should suffice

```
var express = require("express");
```

Also, be sure you have Express installed by running

```
$ npm install express
```

See the [Node.js Docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/) for more information about learning Node.js.

Comment: `import` is not necessarily a feature of TypeScript. TypeScript is ES6 with typings. So stuff like import is ES6 native.

Comment: Node now supports this natively so this answer is out of date

Answer (score 59):

I'm shocked `esm` hasn't been mentioned. This small, but mighty package allows you to use either `import` or `require`.

**Install esm in your project**

`$ npm install --save esm`

**Update your Node Start Script to use esm**

`node -r esm app.js`

`esm` just works. I wasted a TON of time with `.mjs` and `--experimental-modules` only to find out a `.mjs` file cannot import a file that uses `require` or `module.exports`. This was a huge problem, whereas `esm` allows you to mix and match and it just figures it out... `esm` just works.

Comment: How do I use esm to debug with the Visual Studio Code debugger? I want to press F5 and start debugging js in VSCode directly.

Comment: If you're using nodemon, update your npm script to `nodemon -r esm app.js` to get automatic reloads with this solution.

Comment: Wow. I did not believe this was true, but it is.

Comment: I just tried it on a complex project after losing a significant time trying other options, and wow, this works just fine ! Thanks

Answer (score 39):

As mentioned in other answers Node JS currently doesn't support ES6 imports.

(As of now, read  EDIT 2)

[Enable ES6 imports in node js](https://timonweb.com/posts/how-to-enable-es6-imports-in-nodejs/) provides a solution to this issue. I have tried this and it worked for me.

Run the command:

```
    npm install babel-register babel-preset-env --save-dev
```

Now you need to create a new file (config.js) and add the following code to it.

```
    require('babel-register')({
        presets: [ 'env' ]
    })
    // Import the rest of our application.
    module.exports = require('./your_server_file.js')
```

Now you can write import statements without getting any errors.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

You need to run the new file which you created with above code. In my case it was `config.js`. So I have to run:

```
    node config.js
```

**EDIT 2:**

While experimenting, I found one easy solution to this issue.

Create `.babelrc` file in the root of your project.

Add following (and any other babel presets you need, can be added in this file):

```
    {
        "presets": ["env"]
    }
```

Install `babel-preset-env` using command `npm install babel-preset-env --save`, and then install `babel-cli` using command `npm install babel-cli -g --save`

Now, go to the folder where your server or index file exists and run using:
        babel-node fileName.js

Or you can run using `npm start` by adding following code to your `package.json` file:

```
    "scripts": {
        "start": "babel-node src/index.js"
    }
```

Comment: How do I do this with electron? I tried like this : `"start": "babel-node electron .",
` but no luck

Comment: @tpbafk I haven't worked on electron. But I found something similar to your problem [javascript - How to set npm start for electron app with 'babel-node --presets es2015,stage-3'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014152/how-to-set-npm-start-for-electron-app-with-babel-node-presets-es2015-stage-3/46014302). Hope it helps

Answer (score 36):

**Error:**  SyntaxError: Unexpected token **import** or SyntaxError: Unexpected token **export**

---

**Solution:** Change all your imports as example

```js
const express               = require('express');
const webpack               = require('webpack');
const path                  = require('path');
const config                = require('../webpack.config.dev');
const open                  = require('open');
```

And also change your `export default = foo;` to `module.exports = foo;`

Comment: I wish you would have explained the export default part a little more.  I am having trouble with that part. The import works great with your answer.

Comment: There is an answer before my answer which has an explanation. But for clarification Node does not support ES6 syntax. When you say Import ... you're using ES6 syntax

Answer (score 21):

In case that you still can't use "import" here is how I handled it:
Just translate it to a node friendly require. Example:

```
import { parse } from 'node-html-parser';
```

Is the same as:

```
const parse = require('node-html-parser').parse;
```

Comment: not true if you are (as is likely the case) using the `export` keyword

Comment: @DanielThompson Sorry if this can be missunderstanding, I'm just giving a workaround for this case, if you work without the `export` keyword, anyways thanks for your helpful note!

Comment: Working for me. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

**babel 7 proposal**
can you add dev dependencies

```
npm i -D @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/register
```

and add a .babelrc in the root

```
{
"presets": [
  [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
     }
    }
  ]
 ]
}
```

and add to the .js file

```
require("@babel/register")
```

or if you run it in the cli, you could use the require hook as -r @babel/register, ex.

```
$node -r @babel/register executeMyFileWithESModules.js
```

Comment: Installing @babel/preset-env and adding it to .babelrc made the trick. No need for @babel/register plugin in my case.

Answer (score 10):

When I was started with express always wanted a solution to use import instead require

```
const express = require("express");
// to 
import express from "express"
```

Many time go through this line:- `Unfortunately, Node.js doesn't support ES6's import yet.`

Now to help other I create new two solutions here

1) [**esm**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm):-

The brilliantly simple, babel-less, bundle-less ECMAScript module loader.
let's make it work

```
  yarn add esm / npm install esm
```

create start.js or use your namespace

```
 require = require("esm")(module/*, options*/)
 // Import the rest of our application.
 module.exports = require('./src/server.js')
 // where server.js is express server start file
```

Change in your `package.josn` pass path of `start.js`

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node start.js",
    "start:dev": "nodemon start.js",
  },
  "dependencies": {
+    "esm": "^3.2.25",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
+   "nodemon": "^1.19.2"
  }
```

2) [**Babel js**](https://babeljs.io):-

*This can be divide into 2 part*

a) [**Solution 1**](https://timonweb.com/posts/how-to-enable-es6-imports-in-nodejs/) thanks to timonweb.com

b) **Solution 2**

use [**Babel 6**](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/6.26.3/index.html) (older version of [babel-preset-stage-3 ^6.0](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/6.26.3/babel-preset-stage-3))
 create `.babelrc` file at your root folder

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "stage-3"]
}
```

Install babel-preset-stage-3

```
yarn add babel-cli babel-polyfill babel-preset-env bable-preset-stage-3 nodemon --dev
```

Change in package.json

```
"scripts": {
+   "start:dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node -- ./src/index.js",
+   "start": "npm run build && node ./build/index.js",
+   "build": "npm run clean && babel src -d build -s --source-maps --copy-files",
+   "clean": "rm -rf build && mkdir build"
},
"devDependencies": {
+    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
+    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
+    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
+    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
+    "nodemon": "^1.19.4"
},
```

Start your server

```
yarn start / npm start
```

Oooh no we create new problem

```
regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee(email, password) {
^
ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
```

This error only come when you use async/await in your code. 
Then use polyfill that includes a custom regenerator runtime and core-js. 
add on top of `index.js`

```
import "babel-polyfill"
```

This allow you to use async/await

use [Babel 7](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/index.html)

Need to upto date every thing in your project
let start with babel 7
.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Some change in package.json

```
"scripts": {
+  "start:dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node -- ./src/index.js",
+  "start": "npm run build && node ./build/index.js",
+  "build": "npm run clean && babel src -d build -s --source-maps --copy-files",
+  "clean": "rm -rf build && mkdir build",
    ....
}
"devDependencies": {
+   "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
+   "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
+   "@babel/node": "^7.0.0",
+   "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
+   "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
+   "nodemon": "^1.19.4"
....
}
```

and use `import "@babel/polyfill"` on start point

```
import "@babel/polyfill"
import express from 'express'
const app = express()

//GET request
app.get('/', async (req, res) {
  // await operation
  res.send('hello world')
})
app.listen(4000, () => console.log(' Server listening on port 400!'))
```

Are you thinking why `start:dev`

Seriously.  It is good question if you are new. Every change you are boar with start server every time
then use `yarn start:dev` as development server every change restart server automatically for more on [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)

Answer (score 9):

if you can use 'babel', try to add build scripts in package.json(--presets=es2015) as below. it make to precompile import code to es2015

```
"build": "babel server --out-dir build --presets=es2015 && webpack"
```

Comment: but will my call to `npm start` first do the "build", or first do the "start"?  

(The start is currently defined: `"nodemon src/app.js --exec \"npm run lint && node\"",`

Comment: if i run this cmd, it shows server doen't exist error

Answer (score 9):

As of Node.js v12 (and this is probably fairly stable now, but still marked "experimental"), you have a couple of options for using ESM (**E**CMA**S**cript **M**odules) in Node.js (for files, there's a third way for evaling strings), here's what [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) says:

> The `--experimental-modules` flag can be used to enable support for
> ECMAScript modules (ES modules).
>
> Once enabled, Node.js will treat the following as ES modules when passed to
> `node` as the initial input, or when referenced by `import` statements within
> ES module code:
>
> - Files ending in `.mjs`.
> - Files ending in `.js`, or extensionless files, when the nearest parent
>   `package.json` file contains a top-level field `"type"` with a value of
>   `"module"`.
> - Strings passed in as an argument to `--eval` or `--print`, or piped to
>   `node` via `STDIN`, with the flag `--input-type=module`.
>
> Node.js will treat as CommonJS all other forms of input, such as `.js` files
> where the nearest parent `package.json` file contains no top-level `"type"`
> field, or string input without the flag `--input-type`. This behavior is to
> preserve backward compatibility. However, now that Node.js supports both
> CommonJS and ES modules, it is best to be explicit whenever possible. Node.js
> will treat the following as CommonJS when passed to `node` as the initial input,
> or when referenced by `import` statements within ES module code:
>
> - Files ending in `.cjs`.
> - Files ending in `.js`, or extensionless files, when the nearest parent
>   `package.json` file contains a top-level field `"type"` with a value of
>   `"commonjs"`.
> - Strings passed in as an argument to `--eval` or `--print`, or piped to
>   `node` via `STDIN`, with the flag `--input-type=commonjs`.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to address another problem within the original question that no one else has.  After recently converting from CommonJS to ESM in my own NodeJS project, I've seen very little discussion about the fact that you cannot place imports wherever you want, like you could with require.  My project is working great with imports now, but when I use the code in the question, I first get an error for not having a named function.  After naming the function, I receive the following...

```
import express from 'express'
       ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:88:18)
```

You cannot place imports inside functions like you could require.  They have to be placed at the top of the file, outside code blocks.  I wasted quite a bit of time on this issue myself.

So while all of the above answers are great at helping you get imports to work in your project, none address the fact that the code in the original question cannot work as written.

Comment: thanks, that was the issue, though very annoying. my import list at the top is going to be 100 lines long. makes it easier to manage when everything that has to do with a particular API call is all in one spot

Answer (score 4):

`import` statements are supported in the stable release of Node since version 14.x LTS.

All you need to do is specify `"type": "module"` in `package.json`.

Comment: I use node 14.17.5 but canot use `import`.

Comment: It's supported. But not without extra config. You still either need to specify `"type": "module"` as I mentioned or use `.mjs` extension for your file.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was looking after `.babelrc` file, and it should contain something like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015-node5", "stage-3"],
  "plugins": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My project uses node v10.21.0, which still does not support ES6 `import` keyword. There are multiple ways to make node recognize `import`, one of them is to start node with `node  --experimental-modules  index.mjs` (The `mjs` extension is already covered in one of the answers here). But, this way, you will not be able to use node specific keyword like `require` in your code. If there is need to use both nodejs's `require` keyword along with ES6's `import`, then the way out is to use the `esm` npm package. After adding `esm` package as a dependency, node needs to be started with a special configuration like: `node -r esm index.js`

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to get this working. Here's what works:

1. Use a recent node version. I'm using v14.15.5. Verify your version by running: node --version
2. Name the files so that they all end with .mjs rather than .js

---

**Example:**

**mod.mjs**

```
export const STR = 'Hello World'
```

**test.mjs**

```
import {STR} from './mod.mjs'
console.log(STR)
```

**Run:** node test.mjs

You should see "Hello World".

Answer (score 0):

The best option so far I found after all experiment is Babel which is a production-ready solution and very easy to implement

First install npm i @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/register

Create a .babelrc file in the root of your project

{
"presets": [
"@babel/preset-env"
]
}

Create a main.js file and provide an entry point

require('@babel/register')({})
module.exports = require('./app.js')

Package.json

"scripts": {
"start": "node app.js",
"dev": "nodemon app.js"
}

and now you are good to use import syntax without changing the file extension

Reffernce link > https://github.com/Aakashdeveloper/May_Node_Mrng_23/tree/master/weatherapp

Answer (score 0):

using nodejs **v20**

save the files with extension **.mjs** rather than **.js**

to import use statement

```js
import {source_func} from './source_file.mjs'
```

Answer (score -2):

Simply install a higher version of Node. As till Node v10 es6 is not supported. You need to disable a few flags or use