# Why won't my ES6 node app run in elastic beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, babeljs

My `package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node --presets es2015 server.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "~6.2.2"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.16.1",
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "faker": "^3.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4"
  }
}
```

And my `.elasticbeantalk/config.yml` is

```
branch-defaults:
  master:
    environment: mysite-api-dev
    group_suffix: null
global:
  application_name: mysite-api
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: mysite-aws
  default_platform: Node.js
  default_region: us-east-1
  profile: eb-cli-mysite
  repository: null
  sc: git
```

But when I deploy and execute, I get a `502` error. So then I checked some logs and it seems to be that ES6 isn't supported:

```
============= i-0c6e00622a7b74a8f ==============
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log
-------------------------------------
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
/var/app/current/server.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import _ from 'lodash'
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Node is running on your EBS instance?

Comment: How can I find out? Shouldn't it respect my `engines` in `package.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like that you are using eb CLI tool!

Just use `eb status` in your workspace, and see the platform field to check the current running version of Node.

Documentation of eb CLI: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-status.html

Comment: `Platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v3.3.1 running Node.js`

Comment: I'm actually not that familiar with Node, but it seems like that ES6 is not supported by Node yet: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/53

Comment: Similar question about import in NodeJS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import