# How to set npm start for electron app with "babel-node --presets es2015,stage-3"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, babeljs

I'm trying to get my `npm start` working for electron.
I know that you usually start a not distributed/packed app with `electron .` or `./node_modules/.bin/electron .`. Since I was playing around with NodeJS v8.4.0 together with ES6/7 syntax I did end up with this `npm start` script in my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node main.js --presets es2015,stage-3"
  }
```

Everything worked well I was able to use `import` for example without any issues. Now I want to use electron together on the fly with this script. I was wondering if that is possible anyhow? I already tried to change my script to this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/electron . babel-node main.js --presets es2015,stage-3"
}
```

Which gave me a `TypeError` for using `import`.

Also tried this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node main.js ./node_modules/.bin/electron . --presets es2015,stage-3"
  }
```

This ended up doing nothing...

Without bloating this question any further I've tried already changing alot with no luck.

Is there any possible way to use `babel-node main.js --presets es2015,stage-3` to start electron with the given preset so that I can use my syntax without using `Gulp` for example to transpile my files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I've found a solution.
There is a super good helper out there called [electron-compile](https://github.com/electron/electron-compile)
After following the instructions on the github site I can use my `npm start` like this:

If electron is installed locally:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/electron ."
  }
```

If electron is installed globally:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  }
```

Comment: or if you installed it globally: `electron .`