# Setup babel-node and express

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I trying setup ExpressJS server with babel and nodemon. My **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "dnz-home-server",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node ./src/index.jsx --presets=react-app"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

when I run command `yarn start` I get this error

```
Error: Using `babel-preset-react-app` requires that you specify `NODE_ENV` or `BABEL_ENV` environment variables. Valid values are "development", "test", and "production". Inste
```

ad, received: undefined.

I added cross-env to script start:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development BABEL_ENV=development babel-node ./src/index.jsx --presets=react-app"
  },
```

then I get this error

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import express from 'express';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

why I am doing wrong?

Comment: Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue.

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "7.1"
        }
      }
    ],
    "react-app"
  ]
}
```