# how to build npm package for node and web?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I need to develop a npm package like [wpcom-xhr-request](https://github.com/Automattic/wpcom-xhr-request), this package can be used in node and web,  I cloned this package and give it a new name , create a personal git package.  it can only work in web, when it is used in node, it give this error:

```
import requestHandler from 'acme-xhr-request';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
```

why does `wpcom-xhr-request` can be used at both environment? how can do this without `n8-make`? currently , `makefile` make our work a litter complex , I don't like to introduce new complexity。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the version of node you're using doesn't understand import yet. It can be enabled via experimental features of node, but you'll need to use the `require` syntax (not import), or transpile it down to ES5 with a tool like babel for now.

[Node.js - SyntaxError: Unexpected token import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import)

Setup webpack for your node app, then install the babel-loader to transpile the ES6 javascript down to ES5.

https://github.com/babel/babel-loader

Comment: hi, thanks for your help,  the problem is I copied all files from ` wpcom-xhr-request`, build this new package , it doesn't work in browser and node, why does `wpcom-xhr-request` work , but mine? can you use that package as an example show me what I did wrong, please?

Comment: you are right , I did't use bable  to transcode es6, however I also didn't find  babel-loader configuration in  the `wpcom-xhr-request` , I am wondering why it works.