# How to export a TypeScript module so that can be imported both from TypeScript and Node?

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, export, commonjs

Let's say a have the following TypeScript module:

```
function foo () {
  return 123;
}

//TODO: Export code here
```

I want to export it in such a way that can be imported in these ways from TypeScript:

```
import foo from 'foo';
import * as foo from 'foo';
```

and in this way from Node:

```
const foo = require ( 'foo' );
```

Requirements:

- I don't what the users of my module to have to set the `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` option
- I want the code for exporting the module to be as clean as possible
- I want to preserve type definitions

So far I've come up with the following "solutions", but they either don't preserve type definitions well enough or are too verbose:

```
export = foo['default'] = foo as typeof foo & { default: typeof foo };
export = foo['default'] = foo;
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: You have to first determine so you want to publish a commonjs package or a esm package. You then use tooling to create different distributables.

Comment: You have to use `esModuleInterop` if you want both `import foo` and `import * as foo` to give you the same thing. That is not ES spec compliant module behavior.

Comment: @unional I'm exporting it as a commonjs package.
@Aaron if I set `esModuleInterop` in my TS package's `tsconfig.json` file I don't see anything chaning in the compiled code, should I export the module in a particular way?

Comment: In that case yes, you don’t need webpack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best that I could come up with:

```
export = Object.assign ( foo, { default: foo } );
```

It's pretty terse, type definitions are properly generated, and it can be imported using all the aforementioned methods.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know export and imports is not supported in NodeJS yet.
Check this article: [node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import)

And as far as I know the only way to use TypeScript types syntax is only in a `.ts` file so an option is to compile your needed `.ts` files to `.js` using Babel.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm doing already. But I can't find a find of actually exporting the module cleanly from TS so that it generates the right type definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are publishing as a commonjs package, you don't need rollup/webpack.

All you need is to transpile your code to es5 in commonjs using the TypeScript compiler.

Your tsconfig.json should look like this:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "dist" // customize this yourself.
    ...
  }
}
```

And in your package.json:

```
// package.json
{
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "typings": "dist/inde.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist" // customize this yourself.
  ],
  ...
}
```

Here is an example repository you can take a look into:

https://github.com/unional/path-equal

Comment: My module's configuration actually looks like this, the problem is that I can't import it in all the ways that I described in the original post. I guess maybe what I'm trying the compiler to output is not spec-compliant commonjs (?) but that's what I want, a module that I can import in all those ways that I described.

Comment: Since your decided to distribute the package as commonjs, keep it as is and let the consumer to consume it with `import x from 'x'` when they have `esModuleInterop` or `import x = require('x')` when they do not.
You should not try to out-wit the system. That will just create more problems down the road.

Comment: the problem is that these modules are not new, I'm already importing them in existing projects with something like `import foo from 'foo'` from TypeScript, but I also want other folks to be able to write `const foo = require ( 'foo' )` instead of the weird `const foo = require ( 'foo' ).default`. I can't just rewrite all those imports, and I don't want to do a major version bump just for this.

Comment: If you really want that behavior, you can do this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16093#issuecomment-304589484

However, it is really a step backward. Since you are upgrading your code to a different module syntax, make it a breaking change and let the consumption side deal with it, IMO. Don't complicate things more than it is necessary. You will very likely regret this decision in the future.