# Node.js- SyntaxError: Unexpected token import after adding react view

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

Version for Node v8.11.3 and NPM v6.2.0

Showing code

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

Error details

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

My api with nodejs and expressjs working fine. After adding react view it's showing error. My app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Feed from './components/Feed'
import Profile from './components/Profile'
import ArticleView from './components/ArticleView'
import Editor from './components/Editor'
import requireAuthentication from './utils/requireAuth'
import SignInWith from './components/SignInWith'
//import  from './components'

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const pathname = window.location.pathname
        return ( 
            <div>
            { !pathname.includes('editor') ? <Header /> : '' }
            <SignInWith />
                <Switch>

                    <Route exact path="/" component={Feed} />
                    <Route path="/profile/:id" component={Profile} />
                    <Route path="/articleview/:id" component={ArticleView} />
                    <Route path="/editor" component={requireAuthentication(Editor)} />
                    <Route path="**" component={Feed} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js - SyntaxError: Unexpected token import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import)

Comment: This answer for nodejs and express those are working fine  Problem raised after adding react. @Egor Zaremba

Comment: Can you show us the full code sample?

Comment: Where are you adding this view? Why are you mentioning the backend at all? Are you adding this code to the backend?

Comment: No, it's view part app.js

Comment: This is a webpack build issue - you probably need to compile React from ES6 imports to ES5 requires before using it here.