# issue importing a js file using import

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a class that I am trying to import for testing.

```
// animal.js

export default class Animal {
   // code here
}
```

then in my test.js file I have the following:

```
import Animal from './animal.js
```

When I run yarn start test I see the following error message.

> import Animal from './animal.js';

```
   ^^^^
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at new Script (vm.js:83:7)

My package.json file looks like this

```
{
  "name": "animal",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "lazy.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.1",
    "mocha": "^3.5.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you set up babel?

Comment: There are serveral typos and inconsistencies in the question, obscuring the real problem. Please reduce the problem to a [mcve] and then **copy and paste** the necessary parts of it into the question, to avoid introducing irrelevant issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js - SyntaxError: Unexpected token import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import)

Comment: `import Animal from './animal.js` but you get an error `import Animal from './animal.jsw';`? Where is the **w** coming from? And isn't it `export class` lowercase **c**?

Comment: that was safari making class uppercase when I typed it

Comment: Is it a NodeJS project, and if so, what version ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using NodeJS, but it doesn't support that kind of import. If you would like to use it you must use babel or a similar framework.