# Specifying ES6 modules in Node 12

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

From my understanding, I can use ES6 imports with Node 12 if I have the line `"type": "module"` in my `package.json` file. I'm trying to test this, but I can't get it to work. Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "run": "clear;clear; node package/index.js",
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

and my `package/index.js` file:

```
import * as fs from 'fs'
```

running `npm run-script run` outputs

```
import * as fs from 'fs'
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/esm.html#esm_enabling) and [this](https://medium.com/@nodejs/announcing-a-new-experimental-modules-1be8d2d6c2ff) announcement blog article, for `"type": "module"` to work you also need to set the `--experimental-modules` flag when running Node. So in your case the package file script would be:

```
"run": "clear; clear; node --experimental-modules package/index.js",
```

Note that this will also enable a warning at startup:

```
ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
```

Comment: I must've misread, because I thought `--experimental-modules` was for versions of lode less than 12. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

I originally wanted to add comment instead of answer but my reputation is too low to allow me comment. So I place my 'comments' here. Hope everyone understand.

To those who are being directed to this post, [here is the most popular Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import). In short, Node 12 is so tricky that it is the only version support ES6 `import` but **requires --experimental-modules flag to run.**

I was so confused at first when I see Node12 is supposed to be ES6 compatible but failed in running import statement :(