# Nodemon crashes when trying to use es6 modules but works well with es5

Tags: node.js, express, babeljs, es6-modules

I am trying to run a server using es6 modules but crashes every time I do it and works whenever I use it with es5[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uDdA.png)

I have babel installed and have "preset": ["env"] in my .babelrc file but whenever I run it, I have a "syntax error: Invalid or unexpected token". And this is not on one particular project, this is the third project where am experiencing this

```
import http from 'http';
import express from 'express';
import logger from 'morgan';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

// setting up express application
const app = express();

const hostName = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;
const server = http.createServer(app);

// logs request to the console
app.use(logger('dev'))

// Parse incoming data requests
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

// making a request to the server
app.get('*', (req, res) => res.status(200).send({
    message: 'Welcome to the default API route',
}));

server.listen(port, hostName, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostName}:${port}/`);
});
```

it supposed to bring out "Welcome to the default API route" to the console but instead, it is an error message. And if the repo is needed, i will gladly supply it

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: `npm start` from my package.json file

Comment: You'll need to run it under Babel or use Node's ES6 support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ES6 is not yet supported in the Node runtime by default. You can integrate it like this:

1. `npm i esm && npm i -D nodemon`
2. In your package.json, add this to scripts:

`"start": "nodemon -r esm index.js"`

(make sure the `index.js` part of the script matches the name of your server entry point file)

3. Run `npm start`

Comment: When i tried what you said I should, i got this error below and it occured during installation of esm

**npm WARN bookstore@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Adewale\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-10T14_19_21_339Z-debug.log**

Comment: Holy smokes, I created a stackoverflow on stackoverflow. I will look into why this is happening.

Comment: Unless you're open to upgrading to Node v.12.0, which is experimental, it looks like require statements are a better bet:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import

Comment: yeah, require works fine but the moment i switch to using es6 modules, it starts acting up

Comment: ES6 imports are not supported in Node until v12

Comment: The esm Node module has not been updated since 2019. This does ot work correctly for me since it does not handle optional chaining correctly i.e. `response?.ok` is identified as a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

## Solution to running nodemon with support for ES6 module import/export syntax.

first, install the esm package:

```
npm i esm
```

second, ensure package.json contains the line

```
"type": "module"
```

example package.json:

> line 6

```
{
  "name": "stack-overflow-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "express": "^4.18.1"
  }
}
```

To run nodemon:

```
nodemon esm path-to-your/index.js
```

> the file extension is necessary

Comment: Would it make more sense to install esm as a dev dependency?