# Why node.js ignores the "type" setting in the package.json file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Node version:

> node -v
>   v12.13.0

I read [this documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/esm.html#esm_enabling) about using ES modules in Node.js:

> Node.js will treat as `CommonJS` all other forms of input, such as `.js`
>   files where the nearest parent `package.json` file contains no top-level
>   `"type"` field

This is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "name": "sandbox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./src/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ramda": "^0.26.1"
  }
}
```

this is my `./src/index.js`:

```
import R from "ramda";
const src = {name:"Bob",age:7};
const _src = R.clone(src);
console.log(_src);
```

I try to start my code via `npm start` or `node ./src/index.js` but I get the error:

> import R from "ramda";
>   ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Why does it happen? I.e. why node ignores my `"type": "module"` setting?

At the same time it works fine:

```
node --experimental-modules .\src\index.js
```

Comment: Try this : `node --experimental-modules index.js` # Runs as ES module

Comment: ES6 modules are not yet completely supported, they are still in experimental phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Node 12 you need to run node with the `--experimental-modules` flag to enable support for ECMAScript modules.

`import` is part of ES6, it not yet supported in NodeJS by default. it could be working by replacing import with `require`. Or you can use `.babelrec` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54249104/11070678).

Also For ES module usage, the value of "main" must be a full path including extension: "./src/index.js", not "index.js".

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "main": "./src/index.js"
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --experimental-modules ./src/index.js"  
  },
}
```

Comment: > *At last ramda should get import with...*  Why? My code works too as I see...

Comment: I've tried this with Node v8.11.4, at first. `import R from 'ramda'  trowed me an _ SyntaxError: _ The requested module does not provide an export named 'default', then I change it to what I've suggested and everything works,  at the time i was using  `.mjs` extension for my index file as was suggested in docs for that version for being able to use modules. I then update my Node to V12 and  didn't change any of the code,just rename `index.js`.