# How can I export the files that I created to my app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I'm structuring my code to become more readable and maintainable at the same time.

here is my GET.articles and my INSERT.articles is just the same with this.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/sample', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Nice")
})

module.exports = router;
```

my index.js

```
const GET_articles = require('./GET.articles');
const INSERT_articles = require('./INSERT.articles');


exports { GET_articles, INSERT_articles}
```

and I import it like this:

```
app.use('/example', require('./routes/articles_controller/index'));
```

This is my error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your first block of code:

> ```
> module.exports = router;
> ```

Do **that**.

Change:

> ```
> exports { GET_articles, INSERT_articles}
> ```

to

```
module.exports = { GET_articles, INSERT_articles}
```

---

If you want to use `import` and `export` then see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import).

---

Then note that a plain object isn't something you can just `use`.

You should use the routers and not the object containing them.

```
const routers = require('./routes/articles_controller/index');
app.use('/example', routers.GET_articles);
app.use('/example', routers.INSERT_articles);
```

Answer (score -1):

app.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const exampleRoute = require('./routes/articles_controller/index');
var app = express();
 app.use('/', router)

app.use('/example', router, exampleRoute);

router.get('/sample', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Nice")
})

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log("Listening on port 3000")
})
```

route file

```
const GET_articles = require('./GET.articles');
const INSERT_articles = require('./INSERT.articles');
module.exports = [GET_articles, INSERT_articles]
```

GET articles files

```
module.exports = function getArticle (req, res) {
    //Logic as required goes here
    res.send("Content to be rendered")
}
```