# How to construct an imported class in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make some discord bots, and I'm getting frustrated trying to use a class I created in another script. The script in question looks like this:

```js
// utils.js

class BotUtils {
   constructor(param1, param2, ...) {
      this.param1 = param1;
      this.param2 = param2;
      ...
      }

    someMethod() {
    doSomething;
    }
}

module.exports = {BotUtils};
```

In my bot script, I have:

```js
// bot.js
const botUtils = require('./BotUtils');

let utils = new BotUtils(param1, param2, ...);
```

And I get `TypeError: BotUtils is not a constructor`

I've also tried using `new` but it doesn't work. I need to construct the class with the specific parameters. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exporting an *object* with the class `BotUtils` as a  property from your module. To create an instance of the class, you need to reference the property i.e.

```
let utils = new botUtils.BotUtils(param1, param2, ...);
```

If you want to export only the `BotUtils` class then you can do so by removing the brackets

```
module.exports = BotUtils;
```

Then when you require the module the class is what is returned, this is closer to your original code but with a small tweak

```
const BotUtils = require('./utils');
```

Additionally, if you are using [ES modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html), this gets a lot easier with named exports

```
import { BotUtils } from './utils'
```

Comment: Christ, I've been bashing my head against the desk for hours trying to fix this and it's that simple. Thanks!

Comment: Also I tried using ES modules but that was a whole other headache so I went back to the normal exports. Works now though.

Comment: @dbm that's a whole other [can of worms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import). It was on the off chance you were using ES6 already.