# Why not possible to use ES imports in vue.config.js file with VueJS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

Why aren't [ES imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) working in `vue.config.js` file?

In example:

```
import * as path from 'path';
import * as pjson from './package.json';

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': path.join(__dirname, '/src'), // Alias @ to /src folder for ES/TS imports
      },
    },
  },
  pwa: {
    name: pjson.title,
    assetsVersion: pjson.version,
  },
};
```

Getting error after running `npm run lint` command (which uses vue-cli-service):

```
\vue.config.js:1
import * as path from 'path';

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:720:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:6
```

Also `import 'path';` is not working either (tried also other syntax variants):

```
import 'path';
       ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

The reason I'm trying to refactor from `const path = require('path');` syntax is to avoid this new linter error after ESLint plugins upgrade:

> Require statement not part of import
>   statement. eslint(@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires)

But it seems I still need to append this on top of the file: `/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import because node.js builds your app.

Comment: I'm aware there are similar questions specific to NodeJS, however I'm interested about this in the context of Vue CLI.

Comment: For example it seems using ES imports in Node is possible with enabling this experimental flag: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/esm.html#esm_enabling
Using this just for vue.config.js file with Vue CLI may not be in the core team's interest, but I'm not aware of the internals of Vue CLI...perhaps it could have other uses as well.

Answer (score 5):

The file vue.config.js is loaded by @vue/cli-shared-utils/lib/module.js via CommonJS require. Because of that, it expects vue.config.js to be CommonJS, too.

There are a few schemes you could employ to overcome this built-in limitation such as using vue.config.js to

```
require('@babel/register');
```

then require another file like vue.config.mjs where your ESM-based code resides.

But given this is only a config file that usually doesn't have a lot of code, it may be better not to fight city hall and instead use CommonJS.