# How to run javascript function from .js file via console?

Tags: javascript

I want to run some function inside javascript file via the console.

I'm using Node v12.14.1.

My case is as follows:

I have a `testIt.js` file as follows:

```
import {settings} from "./config";

const someMainFunction = (testParam) => {
    console.log("This is init");
    console.log("This PARAM", testParam);
    otherFunction();
};

const otherFunction = () => {
    console.log("This is other function")
};

export { someMainFunction }
```

I want to run `someMainFunction` via console.

I tried with

```
node -e 'require("./testIt").someMainFunction("Testing...")'
```

But it doesn't work.

I do not want to use any external libraries.

Any idea how to do that?

UPDATE

I get an error as follows:

```
import {settings} from "./frontend/config";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at [eval]:1:1
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:20)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:306:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:9:26)
```

I've tried also with:

```
node --harmony testIt.js
```

But I get the same error.

**UPDATE 2**

When I try with

```
node --experimental-modules testIt.mjs
```

I get an error as follows:

```
(node:99449) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
internal/modules/esm/default_resolve.js:84
  let url = moduleWrapResolve(specifier, parentURL);
            ^

    Error: Cannot find module /Users/username/Projects/config imported from /Users/username/Projects/testIt.mjs
        at Loader.resolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/default_resolve.js:84:13)
        at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:73:33)
        at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:147:40)
        at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:41:40)
        at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:40:36) {
      code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
    }
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
import {settings} from "./frontend/config";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at [eval]:1:1
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:20)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:306:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:9:26)
```

Comment: Which version of node?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov v12.14.1

Comment: I believe in that version es modules can be enables under harmony flag. If you have a chance try v13.7, it's enabled by default

Comment: Also can you include in the post what exactly is not working, do you get error or empty screen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js - SyntaxError: Unexpected token import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import)

Comment: You can do following: `node --experimental-modules --input-type=module --eval 'import ....'`. Check https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/esm.html

Comment: Or utilize this https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-register