# Cannot use import statement outside modules

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express, next.js

I am using NextJS with typescript, mongo Atlas, mongoose, node and express.

I am getting the following error when I run node pages/server:
I have uploaded my package.json file and have added babel as well

> import express from 'express'; ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
>       at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:16)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:27)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
>       at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
>       at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47

This is my server.js code:

```
import express from 'express';
import { connect, connection } from 'mongoose';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import path from 'path';
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
//Success
   import routes from './routes/api.tsx';

const MONGODB_URI = 'xxx';

// const routes=require('./routes/api')
connect(MONGODB_URI ||'mongodb://localhost/success', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('Mongoose is connected');
});

const newBlogPost = new BlogPost(data); //instance of the model

app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use('/',routes)

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server is starting at ${PORT}`));
```

**package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "la-sheild",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "babel-node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.2",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.7.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "concurrently": "^5.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.1",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "next": "^9.2.2",
    "node": "^13.8.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/register": "^7.8.3",
    "@types/node": "^13.7.4",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.21",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
}
```

Comment: have you installed express? i.e. Is express exists in package.json file?

Comment: Yes, it does:
"dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.2",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.7.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "concurrently": "^5.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",

@DeepKakkar

Comment: Have you Enabled ES6 Imports?

Comment: https://timonweb.com/posts/how-to-enable-es6-imports-in-nodejs/

Comment: Can you please share  your package.json file?

Comment: Please show your tsconfig.js ( typescript configuration file)

Comment: I have shared my package.json file @DeepKakkar in my code

Comment: here https://prnt.sc/r7cppm @JuhilSomaiya. As stackoverflow is not allowing me to mention more code

Comment: which node version are you using?

Comment: @Rebel, can you please remove esnext from module and add 'es2015' instead in your tsconfig.js

Comment: But I need it to be on the latest version instead of es2015

Comment: v12.16.1 @DeepKakkar

Comment: Also try to add 'es2015' in lib object and see what happens.

Comment: But I am using NEXT js and if I add es2015 it will not give me necessary modules. Also es2015 is old. It conflicts with my new import statements @JuhilSomaiya

Comment: Also I tried changing it to what u told to es2015, still the same error @JuhilSomaiya

Comment: @Rebel Since Node v12, you can use either the .mjs extension or set "type": "module" in your package.json.

And you need to run node with the --experimental-modules flag.

Comment: You should replace all of the `import` with `require` in `server.js`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since Node v12, you can use either the `.mjs` extension or set `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`.

And you need to run node with the -`-experimental-modules` flag.

```sh
node --experimental-modules server.mjs
```

You can check the [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import)

Or you can create `.babelrc` file in the root of your project.
Add following (and any other babel presets you need, can be added in this file):

```
{
    "presets": ["env"]
}
```

Install `babel-preset-env` using

```sh
npm install babel-preset-env
npm install babel-cli -g

# OR

yarn add babel-preset-env
yarn global add babel-cli
```

Now, go to the folder where your `server.js` file exists and

run using:

```sh
babel-node fileName.js
```

Or you can run using npm start by adding following code to your `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node server.js"
}
```

There is a tutorial [link](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/set-up-next-js-with-a-custom-express-server-typescript-9096d819da1c) for Set Up Next.js with a Custom Express Server + Typescript on a medium that will be very helpful for you.

Comment: I do not have a webpack.config.js file

Comment: @Rebel There is a tutorial for you https://levelup.gitconnected.com/set-up-next-js-with-a-custom-express-server-typescript-9096d819da1c

Comment: THANK YOU for this note about babel. Every other thing talks about adding "type": "module" to your package.json which was NOT the solution

Answer (score 12):

The following solution worked for me;

- install needed packages

  `npm install nodemon @babel/core @babel/node @babel/preset-env -D`
- create a **.babelrc** file in the working directory and paste the following in it

  ```
  {
  "presets": [
  "@babel/preset-env" ]
  }
  ```
- lastly, add the code below to `"scripts"` in **package.json**

  `"dev": "nodemon —exec babel-node server.js"`
  where **server.js** is your file in this case.

Hope this works :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution based on [ts-next-express](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/set-up-next-js-with-a-custom-express-server-typescript-9096d819da1c).

```
 npm i --save ts-node
```

create another config file for express because node is using common.js module but if you check the `tsconfig.json` you will see this:`"module": "esnext"`

tsconfig.server.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "noEmit": false
  },
  "include": ["server"]
}
```

set the script as follow:

```
 "start": "ts-node --project tsconfig.server.json server.ts"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same error "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" first i add tye : module but still face another error. Finaly its work for me the issue was this i was running my Driver.js file that why i was getting this issue. i run my Driver.ts file its work ok for me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiYj3.png)

But after run my with extenstion .ts file its work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZSXd.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had my index.ts importing an exported var from my schema.js file.
I was doing an import inside this **schema.js** file
It was this second import causing the 'Cannot use import statement outside modules'.
Finally **renaming the file from schema.js to schema.ts** solved the issue.\

Answer (score -1):

Replace the import statement with the following line of code,

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
```

Answer (score -2):

> "scripts": {
>      "start": "babel-node server.js"
>   }

adding above worked for me