# I get an error when importing a function in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using react-st-modal library to display modals and I am getting an error while importing a function from this library.

My import statement is:

```
const CustomDialogPromise = import("react-st-modal").then(
  (module) => module.CustomDialog
);
```

I am getting error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

UPDATE
I put the import inside useEffect and it dissapeared. Now I'm getting a new error. There is a hook that react-st-modal exports called useDialog and I am importing it in this way:

```
let useDialog = null;
import("react-st-modal")
  .then((module) => module.useDialog)
  .then((dialog) => {
    useDialog = dialog;
  });
```

But then I get the same error as before.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60392949/cannot-use-import-statement-outside-modules

Comment: no, its not applicable to nextjs

Comment: Are you importing this module inside useEffect? How are you using CustomDialogPromise?

Comment: put it in useEffect and it worked. i am now getting a new error. please see the updated question

Comment: I found out how to fix this thanks to this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66244968/nextjs-react-hook-mousetrap-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module

Comment: Why don't you tried import {  useDialog } from 'react-st-modal';?