# I have a syntax error when importing an Observable while I respect the documentation

Tags: node.js

I cannot import the Observable object from RXJS.
I get a syntax error message :

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:267:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:319:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:733:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:300:19)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

My package.json :

```
{
  "name": "testrxjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "myrxjs.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4"
  }
}
```

I installed rxjs with npm.
I do not understand why it does not work.
Could you help me please ?
Thank you in advance.
Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js - SyntaxError: Unexpected token import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import)

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS does not support EcmaScript modules by default. The feature is experimental at the moment. Try to rename your JavaScript files to `.mjs` and run

```
node --experimental-modules ./pathto/script.mjs
```

This should do the trick. If your package.json file contains the field

```
{
  ...
  "type": "module"
}
```

you should don't need to rename the files. The [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) can be really helpful here.

If you are using TypeScript make sure to have the following code in your **tsconfig.json** file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "lib": ["es2017"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2017"
  }
}
```

You should be able to vary the EcmaScript version without problems but the module set to `commonjs` is important.