# I want to access API using async / await

Tags: javascript

Requirements

- I want to use a separate file for the process to access the API
- I want to use async / await
- I want to use axios

The code below will be undefined

- test.js

```
import fetchApi from '../lib/store';

export default function() {

  async function call() {
    const res = await fetchApi();
    console.log(res);//undefined
  }
  call();
}
```

- lib/store.js

```
import axios from "axios"

export default function() {
  async function fetchApi() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "*a separate file for the process*" makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

You're not exporting the `fetchApi` function. You've wrapped it in an anonymous function that does nothing, and therefore returns `undefined`. You're looking for

```
import axios from "axios"

export async function fetchApi() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    return error; // btw, don't do that.
  }
}
```

```
import { fetchApi } from '../lib/store';

export default async function call() {
  const res = await fetchApi();
  console.log(res);
}
```

Comment: How to run this code? I am using Node v10 and I get error
`
import { fetchApi } from '../lib/store';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
`

Comment: @YousufKhan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import

Comment: I was able to understand. Thank you