# (node:9374) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-modules

I just started to learn React today.
How do I get rid of that error message on my Console in the Terminal in Visual Studio.

```
(node: 9374)Warning: To load an ES module,
 set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension. 
/Users/nishihaider/workspace-ui/react-todo-app/src/App.js:1
```

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  <>
  return (
  <h1>ToDo</h1>
  );
  </>
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js - SyntaxError: Unexpected token import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import)

Comment: Had the same problem when using ts-node in a monorepo (Angular + Express + single package.json). Explicitly specifying the path to the tsconfig.json fixed the problem: `--project express-server/tsconfig.json`. https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#loading-tsconfigjson

Answer (score 144):

First, install the latest version of Node.js. It has the latest and greatest features.

Second, add the `"type": "module"` line in your `package.json` file.

```
{

  "type": "module"

}
```

Third, use the `--experimental-modules` flag when invoking nodejs:

`node --experimental-modules app.js`

You should be good to go!

An alternative is to avoid adding the "type": "module" line in your package.json file and instead rename your app.js file to app.mjs.

**Note** that now the `require()` syntax **will stop working**.

Comment: you don't need to add the flag `--experimental-modules` anymore, you can simply run `node app.js`

Comment: This may end up with **"ReferenceError: require is not defined"** error in cases you have declaration like: `require('dotenv').config();`

Comment: Have a few packages needs `require`, how do I resolve it? Thanks

Comment: @Jeb50 did you solve that? I'm looking for some answer

Comment: @Jack Don't remember what I did, as I check now still using `require`. Definitely not adding `"type": "module"`.

Comment: @Jeb50 `"type":"module"` definitely isn't going to work for me either. Do you remember if you was having issues to install webpack before getting into this error?

Comment: @Jack I might have rolled back as TOO MUCH work to convert. Will let you know if it rings. :)

Comment: @Jack See if helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68914705/5063031

Comment: @Jeb50 the issue is, a thrid-party library uses alot of `require`s and I cannot change that. I  fixed the require in my own code then I got erros about the thrid-party ones.

Comment: Everyone recommends this but no one warns that since added `"type": "module"` each require() statement must be removed even in dependencies so this solution is not acceptable. Now some packages use require and another import, nightmare, no compatibility between it.

Comment: Is this still current? Does javascript still have 5 ways to use modules?

Comment: ok, but what if it's just one file , in a folder , and you don't even have a package.json, because you're just testing a specific thing.... do you necessarily need to add package.json?

Answer (score 46):

Here is my approach:

1 - Update package.json like:

```
  "main": "index.js",
  "type":"module",
```

2 - use.js when importing, like:

```
import {isPrime} from './isPrime.js';
```

3 - here is isPrime.js

```
export const isPrime ....
```

Comment: I tried this, and it seems to work. Why do I have to add ".js" though? That doesn't seem right - I would expect it to automatically figure out that it needs the ".js" file without having to specify the extension.

Edit: It's apparently an ongoing discussion: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577

Comment: I was removing Babel from my project and this works for me

Answer (score 27):

You just need to update package.json like this,

```
{"type": "module"}
```

It's worked for me,
Thanks!

Comment: Where did you put this in package.json?

Comment: You put it at the root level, so same level as `"name": "server"` etc. I usually put it just under the `"main": "index.js"`

Answer (score 17):

to add Type: module  in package.json - helps :)

package.json contain:

```
{
  "name": "react_template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

For those using TypeScript with node.js, and is trying to use the `import` statement. I have found that setting the `module` to value `es2015` in the `tsconfig.json` gives this error, while setting it to `commonjs` works.

tsconfig.json

```json
    {
     "module": "commonjs"
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Just Change this:**

```
export default App;
```

**To this:**

```
module.exports = App;
```

Comment: The error is on the import, which this change will not resolve.

Answer (score 2):

I have a parent file importing child components, so I get same problem about ES module.
in my case, I must define more details when i import the component. like this:

```js
import db from "../config/Database"; false
import db from "../config/Database.js"; true
```

Another example :

```js
import Users from "../models/UserModel"; incorrect
import Users from "../models/UserModel.js"; correct
```

I don't know why it has to be like this, but when I try the problem is resolved. I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

you are also sorrounding the return statement with React Fragments which is not correct. Your return statement should look like the following:

```
 import React from "react";
 import "./App.css";

 function App() {
   return (
    <>
      <h1>ToDo</h1>
    </>
   );
 }

export default App;
```

I'm quite sure this was the source of your issues all along and not the module import/export issue.

Comment: Do you need to? Isn't a h1 a react element in its own right? Think the addition of the fragement is not necessary / not a solution.

Comment: This would not cause the import on the first line to fail.

Answer (score 1):

adding the "type": "module" line in your package.json file and instead rename your app.js file (or whatever) to app.mjs.

Answer (score 1):

**SIMPLE AND FAST SOLUTION FOR BEGINNERS**

1  ***RENAME YOUR JS FILE MJS*** LIKE  (hello.js >  hello.mjs)

2  ***GIVE MJS FILE NAME IN YOUR  EXPORT***  LIKE  ( `import { first } from './pg.mjs'`)

Comment: What is the explanation for this "solution"? What is a mjs file anyway?