# How to do Import and Require together?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

Node v14, server backend needs Observable and connection to PostgreSql.

- To [create Observable](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable), `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';` is needed.
- Must add `"type": "module"` into pakage.json else `Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json`
- But it makes `require` not working for Postgre connection.

index.js

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
const observable = new Observable(
  subscriber => 
  {
    ...
  });

observable.subscribe({...});
console.log('just after subscribe');
```

To connect to [PostgreSql](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/),

```
const pgp = require('pg-promise')();
const db = pgp({...});
```

Now getting `ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

How can I have both?

Comment: Why aren't you using the [TypeScript syntax for including pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/tree/master/typescript)?

Comment: @vitaly-t Following the sample `import * as pgPromise from 'pg-promise'; const pgp = pgPromise({});` got **TypeError: pgPromise is not a function** pgp version 10.11.0

Comment: U need to configure your TS right, as explained there.

Comment: @vitaly-t I installed TS `npm install typescript -g`, `npm install`, went to typescript folder by `cd node_modules\typescript`, ran `tsc` got a help screen. So I did `tsc --init`, `tsc --build tsconfig.json`. **F5**, same pgPromise is not a function. Any other steps missing?

Comment: @vitaly-t Resolved without TS. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research and try, come back to the same spot, simply replace `require` with `import`. As an example of above,

Original:

```
const pgp = require('pg-promise')();
const db = pgp({...});
```

New:

```
import pgPromise from 'pg-promise';
const pgp = pgPromise({...});
const db = pgp({...});
```