# Fetch external API response as JSON file on build time with node script

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have a react project setup and I want to run some node script on build time to fetch JSON data from external API and save it as a static resource on server and then use that file in the app.

This is the brief overview of the project structure:

```
src
|-dir
|  |-helpers.ts
|
|-node-script.js
```

the node script I am trying to run

```
import fetch from "node-fetch"
import fs from "fs";

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
        fs.writeFile('./src/data.json', JSON.stringify(json), (err) => {
            if (err) {
                throw new Error('Something went wrong writing the file.')
            }
            console.log('JSON written to file. Contents:', JSON.stringify(json));
        })
    })
```

This script doesn't run and gives me this error.

`(node:62124) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension`

I know adding `type:module` in my package.json resolves this but I don't want to do that as I am afraid it will going to mess with other dependencies in the frontend project.

I am not able to find an alternative solution and need some help here.

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63588714/node9374-warning-to-load-an-es-module-set-type-module

Comment: It says right in the console warning, use `.mjs` extension on your node script. Other option would be to use `require` and cjs.

Comment: @morganney yes it works now but I get in to another problem. I get 
```Cannot find module``` 

error when i try to import some functions  from my ```helpers.ts``` file

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your import statements to use require instead

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const fs = require('fs')
```