# Chai Unexpected token when importing

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

So i have this very very simple dummy test:

```
import {expect}  from 'chai';

describe('calculate', function () {
    it('add', function () {
        let result = 2 + 5;
        expect(result).equal(7);
    });
});
```

Here i get the following error when i run it:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { expect } from 'chai';
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Can anyone tell me whats going on?

Comment: Seems like your JS Interpreter does not support ES6 Modules. Do you use NodeJS or WebPack there?

Comment: You may try using require instead of import

Comment: its a NodeJS module i am trying to make test for

Comment: NodeJS does not support ``import`` by default. Look here for further information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import

Comment: @Tracer69 Then how come i am able to do it in my TS files?

Comment: Typescript is not javascript. It gets compiled, and the compiler transforms all ``import`` to ``require`` (Or throws everything in a single file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transpile your code to use commonjs imports. You can use babel for such a task, see the docs https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-modules-commonjs.

Via cli you can run `babel --plugins @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs script.js` and then simply run your script.

If you don't want to use either transpilation (using babel or whatever) or commonjs you could use a loader such as `esm`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm.

From the docs, after running `yarn add esm` you can just `node -r esm main.js`.

Comment: I dont have babel installed yet this is not suppose to run in the browser it is just suppose to be an Nodejs module

Comment: babel is not only used for targeting the browser these days. As a matter of fact it can be considered good practice to typecheck your code using typescript and transpile it using babel (we do this on a server side project). Your problem can be solved by using commonjs imports `const { expect } = require("chai")` or something like that, since es6 are still experimental in node