# Node Cannot Find Modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am new to node and javascript and I'm trying to utilise the following library: https://github.com/Applifting/stv

I am unable to work out why I keep get the following "Error: Cannot find module './stv'"

I've read several similar questions and responses but none of the suggested solutions, such as reinstalling node and npm, have helped.

Below is the setup I went through to set up the package.json and install the stv module.

```
C:\votecount>npm init -y
Wrote to C:\votecount\package.json:

{
  "name": "votecount",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}

C:\votecount>npm add stv
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN votecount@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN votecount@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ stv@0.0.2
added 1 package from 1 contributor and audited 1 package in 1.112s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

The package.json correctly shows stv under the dependencies.

```
  "name": "votecount",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",  
  "dependencies": {
    "stv": "0.0.2"
  },
```

I then created an index.js file containing:

`const stv = require('stv')`

Then when running index.js I get the following.

```
C:\votecount>node index.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './stv'
Require stack:
- C:\votecount\node_modules\stv\dist\index.js
- C:\votecount\index.js
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\votecount\node_modules\←[4mstv←[24m\dist\index.js:3:13)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: [
    ←[32m'C:\\votecount\\node_modules\\stv\\dist\\index.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\votecount\\index.js'←[39m
  ]
}

C:\votecount>node -v
v12.18.4

C:\votecount>npm -v
6.14.6
```

However when I try this process installing the express module I don't have any problems and can import the module succesfully.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
```

As express seems to work fine I'm not sure how to go about troubleshooting this any further. I can see that part of the stv module I am trying to use has been written in typescript but the specific stv package.json seems to handle this.

Any assistance with troubleshooting this error would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
I've also tried using `import { stv } from 'stv';` as per the git instructions but get another error:

```
C:\votecount>node index.js
(node:5432) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
C:\votecount\index.js:1
import { stv } from 'stv';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

If I then add "type": "module" to the package.json in the root directory I then get:

```
C:\votecount>node index.js
(node:15736) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///C:/votecount/index.js:1
import { stv } from 'stv';
         ^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'stv' is expected to be of type CommonJS, which does not support named exports. CommonJS modules can be imported by importing the default export.
For example:
import pkg from 'stv';
const { stv } = pkg;
```

Updating index.js to `import pkg from 'stv'; const { stv } = pkg;` then returns the original "Error: Cannot find module './stv'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package is not published properly. There is only one compiled file `dist/index.js`. There should have been more files.

```
examples  index.d.ts  index.js  model.d.ts  model.js  stv.d.ts  stv.js  stv.spec.d.ts  stv.spec.js  utils.d.ts  utils.js
```

One solution is-

- Fork the repo
- Clone it into your project
- cd into `stv`
- install modules
- run `tsc`

Then

```
const stv = require('./stv/dist')
```

For permanent solution raise issue in the repo. It will be fixed by library owners/maintainers only.

Comment: Thanks Shivam, this has fixed the problem. After running tsc the remaining d.ts and js files were compiled. However, I still needed to use `import stv from 'stv';` to import the module.

Comment: @fortymod  [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the `stv` package has been done with `typescript` and has not been properly transpiled to `javascript` before publishing.

Check if [libre-stv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libre-stv) does what you need, or if any other package works.

Both of them have no use (1 or 2 weekly downloads) so maybe you can find a better package. As last option, copy the functions you need to use and paste them into your project, doing the change to js if needed

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a bug in this package. The `main` property in package.json points to `dist/index.js` but there is no `dist` directory. See it here [stv main property](https://github.com/Applifting/stv/blob/e3aa0ccbcb84633d0dcbdc2126a703b32456a340/package.json#L4)

Since there is no `types": "dist/index.d.ts` too you can't use it in a non typescript environment.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing npm add. Try with npm i stv and then run your program
also try this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/stv