# JavaScript problem with import, weird error

Tags: javascript, import

I have some code using library:

```
import { generateKeyPair } from 'jose/util/generate_key_pair'
async function funkcja () {
const {publicKey, privateKey} = await generateKeyPair('PS256')
console.log(publicKey)
console.log(privateKey)
}
funkcja()
```

and while trying to node it i get following error:

```
  ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/js$ node hello.js
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/js/hello.js:1
import { generateKeyPair } from 'jose/util/generate_key_pair'
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

I have no idea why this is happening, my friend is using exact same library and same code and on his computer it's working fine. (path to the library is correct) The only differennce is that he has node v12 and i have node v10.

Comment: [Does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js - SyntaxError: Unexpected token import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
const { generateKeyPair } = require('jose/util/generate_key_pair');
```

Don't forget to use `module.exports` in `generate_key_pair` js file

Answer (score 0):

How i read it in [Update on ES6 Modules in Node.js](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c) the `import` of variables via curly brackets seems to be not supported in node.js.

> it will simply not be possible to use the syntax:
>
> `import {foo, bar} from 'foobar';`

But this would be possible:

```
import foobar from 'foobar';
console.log(foobar.foo(), foobar.bar());
```

So if `generateKeyPair`  is a variable or function from `'jose/util/generate_key_pair'` it should be:

```
import generate_key_pair from 'jose/util/generate_key_pair'
async function funkcja () {
  const {publicKey, privateKey} = await generate_key_pair.generateKeyPair('PS256')
  console.log(publicKey)
  console.log(privateKey)
}
funkcja()
```