# Trying to run .mjs script on ZX cmmand line

Tags: javascript, shell, scripting

I tried to run this example on my ubuntu os.

https://github.com/google/zx/blob/main/examples/basics.mjs

after I installed zx from npm

via `npm i -g zx`

and run the following cmd:

`sudo zx ./script.mjs`

i got below error:

```
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/zx/zx.mjs:17
    import {basename, dirname, extname, join, parse, resolve} from 'path'
           ^
    
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
        at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
        at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

My npm version is : 7.14.0

Comment: an aside: you didn't need sudo. as for the error itself, i could not replicate it. what's your `zx` version? check with `zx -V`. mine was **1.14.0**. were there any errors during installation of `zx`? try a reinstall just in case `npm -g rm zx && npm -g i zx`

Comment: I tried to reinstall ( i needed to use sudo ) as you said above.

When i tried to run zx -v i got bellow output. 

https://gist.github.com/casdidier/9fa27a33bf7607fe54b1e8e5a7acc946

Comment: capital V `zx -V`. sudo for installing things ; sudo for testing scripts  (generally)

Comment: okay. i just checked. -V and -v are synonymous. so the problem is elsewhere. i am not sure where

Comment: were there any error messages during or after installation?

Comment: Indeed my node version was too old v10,19.0 
I updated to v.14.17.0

My node was not supporting import  ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import )

Now it works fine !

Comment: aha! glad you figured it out. :) i recommend answering your own question and marking as accepted. it'll be helpful for others who come across the same problem in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As exlained in above comments:

The issue originated from an old version node that didn't recognize the `import` feature. which is available only since : v13+ ( see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import)