# When using the ES Module system in Node.js, can all Node packages be imported using the same import syntax?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

This question is not whether Node.js supports the ES Module system.

That question has been answered previously, eg:

[How can I use an ES6 import in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node-js)
[Node.js - SyntaxError: Unexpected token import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import)

And these answers are supported by the official Node.js docs:

> ECMAScript modules are the [official standard format](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-modules) to package JavaScript code for reuse...Node.js fully supports ECMAScript modules as they are currently specified and provides interoperability between them and its original module format, [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).  Node.js has two module systems: CommonJS modules and ECMAScript modules.  Authors can tell Node.js to use the ECMAScript modules loader via the `.mjs` file extension, the package.json ["type"](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#type) field, or the [--input-type](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--input-typetype) flag.

[Source](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#modules-ecmascript-modules)

So it is clear that Node.js supports the ES Module system.

This question is:

When using the ES Module system in Node.js, can all Node packages be imported using the same import syntax?

The reason I ask is that a lot of packages' documentation does not specify how to import them using ES Module style, eg:

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html
https://github.com/expressjs/session

I want to avoid the situation where I am trying to figure out the correct syntax to use each time I want to import a library.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56350495) seems to suggest this syntax:

```
import * as [ whatever_was_previously_used_as_the_variable_name ] from [ whatever_was_previously_between_the_quotes_in_the_parenthesis ]
```

So, using the examples above, this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const session = require('express-session');
```

could safely be converted to:

```
import * as express from 'express';
const app = express();
import * as session from 'express-session';
```

Is that the 'universal' syntax that should be used to import all Node packages?

(*Update: that `session` import above doesn't work, at `app.use(session(sessionConfig));` it caused the error `TypeError: session is not a function` - I needed to define the import like this: `import session from 'express-session'`.  I also had to import [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) like this: `import axios from 'axios'`, or i got a similar error.  However, to use [msal-node](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-node/docs/initialize-confidential-client-application.md#initializing-the-confidentialclientapplication-object) i had to use `import * as msal from '@azure/msal-node'`*).

Just to confuse things, I have come across other syntax examples, such as these in the Node docs (which includes `node:`):

```js
import * as fs from 'node:fs/promises';

// OR:  

import * as fs from 'node:fs';
```

[Source](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#file-system)

I am hoping a definitive answer can be provided that covers the different scenarios that may exist, eg:  Node packages that live in the `node_modules` directory as well as one's own custom JavaScript modules that live outside of `node_modules`.

In this way, if I ever come across a package that does not specify installation instructions using the ES Modules style, I will still know the correct way to import it.

Comment: afaik there's no guarantee it will always work

Comment: "*I have come across other syntax examples, such as these in the Node docs (which includes `node:`)*" - that's still the very same syntax `import * as <namespace> from '<specifier>';`. Nothing different there.

Comment: Yes https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#interoperability-with-commonjs

Comment: Friendly reminder: If an answer was helpful to you, please accept/upvote it. Otherwise, you can comment on it to clarify your needs or request additional info.

Answer (score 2):

The `import` statement is indeed universal and can be used to import a module of either system, whether inside node_modules or out, or built-in to Node. When importing a CommonJS module this way, the value it would normally expose to `require` becomes its default export, so `import name from 'url';`, or any other form of [`import` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) that retrieves the default export, will get you what you need.

The `import * as name from 'url';` form you mentioned is for retrieving all of a module's named exports. This creates a module namespace object, never a function, though the function or other value that a CommonJS module exposes to `require` is available on the `default` property. There's generally no need to use `import *` with a CommonJS module, since everything that Node detects as a named export will be properties on the default export anyways.

You can also [create a `require` from inside an ES module](https://nodejs.org/api/module.html#modulecreaterequirefilename); this will work exactly the same way as `require` in CommonJS, but that includes the limitation of importing only CommonJS and built-in modules, not ES modules.

Comment: require() looks up modules from inside node_modules -folders. Is anything similar available for ES6 imports in Node.js? Or do I always have to provide the exact path to the ES6-module I want to import?

Comment: @PanuLogic Imports in Node.js check node_modules just as require() does.