# How can I check if an import statement is working correctly in the Node 6 REPL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

```
export default config = {
  apiUrl : "http://localhost:7543"
}

$ node --version
v6.7.0
```

Is this possible without transpiling? Is there a way to polyfill in import without having to change my code?

I'd like to pull that in to the console (REPL) and see if the object is set up right. But:

```
import {config} from './config';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

It looks like I can't use import in the REPL yet. So what's the alternative? Do I need to use ES5/Node `require`? Is there a polyfill that I can add in to my loader for Nesh?

**Ideally I'd like to just open up `node` console and use paste in a line that uses `import` without having to change my code.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Import command in Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753364/use-import-command-in-node-js)

Comment: Node.js doesn't support ES 6 modules, you have to use Babel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unexpected reserved word import in node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346886/unexpected-reserved-word-import-in-node-js)

Comment: @Gothdo I read those other questions already; edited mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js doesn't support ES Modules. If you want to use them, you have to transpile your code using Babel.

It's not possible to polyfill ES Modules, because they introduce a new syntax, so the code can't even be parsed properly (you get syntax error).

Comment: This seems like an argument against adopting ES2015 in Node. If I can't copy/paste my code into a REPL that's a downside to me.

Comment: @jcollum You can use [`babel-node`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node).

Comment: No: `SyntaxError: repl: Modules aren't supported in the REPL`